Foreground Service not starting in Android version 14 for my Flutter App
I have implemented Foreground Services for older and newer version of Android in my flutter app. I have done all settings required still its not working. In older version of Android devices below version 14, its working. But for devices with Android version 14, its not working. Please check code and help me.
Call.dart File:
  @override
  void onDestroy(DateTime timestamp, SendPort? sendPort) {
    // TODO: implement onDestroy
  }

  @override
  void onRepeatEvent(DateTime timestamp, SendPort? sendPort) {
    // TODO: implement onRepeatEvent
  }

  @override
  void onStart(DateTime timestamp, SendPort? sendPort) {
    // TODO: implement onStart
  }

}

@pragma('vm:entry-point')
  void startCallback() {
    FlutterForegroundTask.setTaskHandler(FirstTaskHandler());
  }

 Future<void> requestPermissions() async {
    if (!Platform.isAndroid) {
      return;
    }

    final NotificationPermission notificationPermissionStatus =
        await FlutterForegroundTask.checkNotificationPermission();
    if (notificationPermissionStatus != NotificationPermission.granted) {
      await FlutterForegroundTask.requestNotificationPermission();
    }
  }

  Future<bool> _startForegroundTask() async {
    try {
      if (await FlutterForegroundTask.isRunningService) {
        debugPrint("Restarted");
        return FlutterForegroundTask.restartService();
      }
      else {
        debugPrint("started");
        return FlutterForegroundTask.startService(
            notificationTitle: 'Foreground Service',
            notificationText: 'Service Running',
            callback: startCallback);
      }
    }
    catch(e) {
      debugPrint("Foreground $e");
      return false;
    }
  }

  void _initForegroundTask() {
    try {
      FlutterForegroundTask.init(
        androidNotificationOptions: AndroidNotificationOptions(
          foregroundServiceType: AndroidForegroundServiceType.MICROPHONE,
          channelId: 'foreground_service',
          channelName: 'Foreground Service Notification',
          channelDescription: 'This notification appears when the foreground service is running.',
          channelImportance: NotificationChannelImportance.LOW,
          priority: NotificationPriority.LOW,
          iconData: const NotificationIconData(
            resType: ResourceType.mipmap,
            resPrefix: ResourcePrefix.ic,
            name: 'launcher',
          ),
        ),
        iosNotificationOptions: const IOSNotificationOptions(
          showNotification: true,
          playSound: false,
        ),
        foregroundTaskOptions: const ForegroundTaskOptions(
          interval: 5000,
          isOnceEvent: false,
          autoRunOnBoot: true,
          allowWakeLock: true,
          allowWifiLock: true,
        ),
      );
    }
    catch(e) {
      debugPrint("error $e");
    }
  }````
** inside initState():**

```` WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((timeStamp) async {
      await requestPermissions();
      _initForegroundTask();
    });`
```
Implemented all these methods for foreground services.

**Android Manifest.xml**

````<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" package="com.example.support">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" android:maxSdkVersion="30"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_PRIVILEGED"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN" android:usesPermissionFlags="neverForLocation"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE_MICROPHONE" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.hardware.sensor.proximity"/>

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.microphone" android:required="true" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.bluetooth" android:required="false"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.bluetooth_le" android:required="false"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PRIVILEGED_PHONE_STATE"
        tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.gms.permission.AD_ID"
        tools:node="remove"/>
    
    <application
        tools:replace="android:label"
        android:label="Support"
        android:name="${applicationName}"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity" android:exported="true" android:launchMode="singleTop" android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme" android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode" android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <!--
            Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
            the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
            while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
            to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI.
            -->
            <meta-data android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
                android:resource="@style/NormalTheme" />

            <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.wallet.api.enable"
                android:value="true" />

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_channel_id"
                android:value="@string/default_notification_channel_id"/>
            
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.yalantis.ucrop.UCropActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"/>

        <service
            android:name=".MyForegroundService"
            android:foregroundServiceType="microphone"
            android:exported="true">

        </service>
        <!--
        Don't delete the meta-data below.
        This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java
        -->
        <meta-data android:name="flutterEmbedding" android:value="2" />
        <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>
        <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ClientToken" android:value="@string/facebook_client_token"/>
    </application>
</manifest>````

